# How do I query most recent record data based on login datetime in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables to join and show detail of the recent date based on login time.
Could you please advise?

Data from table "sessions"

| USERNAME | CLIENT NAME | VERSION | LOGIN TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_A_1 | 2.1.2 | 7-Mar-22 |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_A_1 | 2.1.1 | 15-FEB-22 |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_B | 3.1.1 | 7-Mar-22 |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_C | 4.1.3 | 27-FEB-22 |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_D | 4.1.5 | 27-FEB-22 |

Data from table "users"

| USERNAME | TASK |
| --- | --- |
| TEST_PROD | messenger |
| TEST_PROD | messenger |
| TEST_PROD | messenger |
| TEST_PROD | messenger |
| TEST_PROD | messenger |

I executed below SQL query:

```
select sessions.USERNAME, sessions.clientname as "CLIENT NAME", sessions.version as "VERSION", users.TASK, MAX(sessions.LOGINTIME) as "LOGIN TIME"
FROM users
RIGHT JOIN sessions on users.USERNAME = sessions.USERNAME WHERE sessions.USERNAME = 'TEST_PROD' AND sessions.LOGINTIME >= to_date('15-FEB-22','DD-MON-YY')
GROUP BY sessions.USERNAME, sessions.clientname, sessions.version, users.TASK;
```

I got below result:

| USERNAME | CLIENT NAME | VERSION | TASK | LOGIN TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_A_1 | 2.1.2 | messenger | 7-Mar-22 |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_A_1 | 2.1.1 | messenger | 15-FEB-22 |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_B | 3.1.1 | messenger | 7-Mar-22 |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_C | 4.1.3 | messenger | 27-FEB-22 |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_D | 4.1.5 | messenger | 27-FEB-22 |

My expectation is below:

| USERNAME | CLIENT NAME | VERSION | TASK | LOGIN TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_A_1 | 2.1.2 | messenger | 7-Mar-22 |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_B | 3.1.1 | messenger | 7-Mar-22 |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_C | 4.1.3 | messenger | 27-FEB-22 |
| TEST_PROD | TEST_D | 4.1.5 | messenger | 27-FEB-22 |

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are attempting to do, you could SELECT DISTINCT ON (username) and ORDER BY LOGINTIME DESC to get your expected results.

```
select distinct on (sessions.username) sessions.USERNAME, sessions.clientname as "CLIENT NAME", sessions.version as "VERSION", users.TASK, MAX(sessions.LOGINTIME) as "LOGIN TIME"
FROM users
RIGHT JOIN sessions on users.USERNAME = sessions.USERNAME WHERE sessions.USERNAME = 'TEST_PROD' AND sessions.LOGINTIME >= to_date('15-FEB-22','DD-MON-YY')
GROUP BY sessions.USERNAME, sessions.clientname, sessions.version, users.TASK
ORDER BY sessions.LOGINTIME DESC;
```

Comment: Hi @Lauri, thank you for the response.
After executing, I got below error message:

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression